# Remove brackets after installing rails-api (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, brackets, rails-api

I installed the rails-api gem. Then I made a new rails app, and set up an `index` action to print rows from the database using `@tasks = Task.all`. In the view I put `<%= @tasks.each do |task| %> <%= task.navn %> <% end %>`

I get this symbol `[]` under the data I did get from the database. All the information I try to print out is in the symbols.

Do anyone have a solution to remove the brackets?

I have pushed my testapp to github so you can see whats in my application.
https://github.com/niiicolai/testruby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= @tasks.each do |task| %>
```

Should be

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
```

notice the lack of `=`

`<%=` means evaluate and execute the code and insert into the html

`<%` means to simply evaluate and execute the code

Comment: Wow that was simple! Thank you so much!